# Should I log transform my volatility variable?

Tags: vector-autoregression, lognormal-distribution, finance, volatility

I'm wondering if my volatility factor is specified correctly. My data consists of log returns on the S&P 500 index, a measure of news sentiment, and a newscount variable (# of articles published on that day). Now I want to include a volatility variable, and I tried several but will explain my current issue.

I used the square of log returns, but as you can imagine, the distribution of it is skew: 10.03 and kurt:132.48. If I take the log of this, it becomes skew:-0.96 and kurt: 5.36. So it is closer to normality now.
Does it make any sense to take the log again?
What can it mean for inference if I were to conduct a VAR analysis? (elasticities?) I did for both and included the table for granger causality, using both log volatility (left) and (unaltered) volatility (right) measures.

I hope someone can help me.
Cheers

[image: Granger Causality table]

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to do, in substantive terms. My blog post [how to ask a statistics question](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) may help. Also, how are you taking log of returns when returns can be negative?

Comment: I calculated the log returns by ln(ret+1) which is the same as the conventional way: ln(Pt+1/Pt). I'm investigating whether news sentiment is driving returns or return volatility and vice versa. In the first place if they do (by making use of granger causality tests) and if possible to what extent (here is where I would like to know how the inference changes)